# Error Upgrading DB to 4.7.18: SQL

Tags: upgrade, database

[Error: Upgrade DB to 4.7.18: SQL] 
 [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'Chandigarh-1101' for key 'UI_name_country_id']

How can I fix the error as given below:

```
INSERT INTO `civicrm_state_province` (`id`, `country_id`, `abbreviation`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, 1101, "CH", "Chandigarh"), (NULL, 1083, "CP", "Central"), (NULL, 1083, "EP", "Eastern"), (NULL, 1083, "NP", "Northern"), (NULL, 1083, "WP", "Western"), (NULL, 1181, "K", "Saint Kitts"), (NULL, 1181, "N", "Nevis"), (NULL, 1190, "E", "Eastern"), (NULL, 1190, "N", "Northern"), (NULL, 1190, "S", "Southern") [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'Chandigarh-1101' for key 'UI_name_country_id']
DebugInfo   INSERT INTO `civicrm_state_province` (`id`, `country_id`, `abbreviation`, `name`) VALUES (NULL, 1101, "CH", "Chandigarh"), (NULL, 1083, "CP", "Central"), (NULL, 1083, "EP", "Eastern"), (NULL, 1083, "NP", "Northern"), (NULL, 1083, "WP", "Western"), (NULL, 1181, "K", "Saint Kitts"), (NULL, 1181, "N", "Nevis"), (NULL, 1190, "E", "Eastern"), (NULL, 1190, "N", "Northern"), (NULL, 1190, "S", "Southern") [nativecode=1062 ** Duplicate entry 'Chandigarh-1101' for key 'UI_name_country_id']
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade for 4.7.18 tries to insert new state in `civicrm_state_province` table. This was done via https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19993.

But seems you already have `Chandigarh` in the table due to which mysql finds a duplicate row already present in the database and eventually displays an error. So the question is how this record is already present in your database?

- Have you tried this upgrade for 4.7.18 before and retrying this again? If yes, try getting a backup of the previous version and then start the upgrade process.
- Have you added the new state `Chandigarh` in your DB manually in your previous version? 
  In this case, you can simply delete the `Chandigarh` entry manually from `civicrm_state_province` table and restart the upgrade. It will create the entry for Chandigarh so you'll not lose any state record from your DB.

Comment: I think you should not delete entries from table since it might have been used in other tables so probably its a good idea to remove the line of code from upgrade script.

Comment: Hi @PradeepNayak,how can I identify the line of code where this insert code is present?

Comment: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.7.18-rc/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/sql/4.7.18.mysql.tpl#L56